# Парсинг с использованием регулярных выражений

Tags: python, json, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть результат с php страницы вида:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"id":1490061,"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["58.539315","31.242983"]}.
```

Моя задача - получить значение поля `id` и `coordinates` с использованием регулярных выражений. Подскажите, какую регулярку здесь можно использовать?

Регулярка для получения id есть и выглядит примерно так:

```
r'"id":(.*?),"type"'
```

Она достает именно значение id. А вот как в рамках неё же прописать координаты, я не знаю.

Comment: Ответ приходит в json?

Comment: Да, в json. Ну скорее в виде текста в формате json.

Comment: прикрепите код с помощью которого вы получаете эти данные

Comment: Немного дополнил текст треда.

Comment: А код простой: 
r = get('https://***.ru/stores.php')
text_stores = r.text

Comment: Хорошо, но я имел ввиду другое) мне интересно как вы получаете эти данные, какие библиотеки используете для запроса

Comment: Используется, собственно говоря, requests :) Вроде бы, можно использовать рекурсию для обхода всего json-объекта/словаря (там порядка 2000 уникальных значений id и координат будет), но я пока вообще не продвинут настолько. Поэтому решил, что проще будет сделать это регуляркой.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `r.text` использовать `r.json()` и работать с полученным объектом как с словарём

Answer (score 1):

```
.*"id":(.+?),.*"coordinates":\[("(.*)","(.*)")\].*
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]